# Drupal db_select and a MYSQL function as a condition

Tags: php, mysql, drupal, drupal-7

Ok so let me explain my situation. I am trying to make a mysql query as such:

```
Select * FROM dates n WHERE (MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(n.date)) = '12');
```

But I need the query to be in the db_select function.

If I add:

```
$this->query->condition('MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(n.date))', 12, '=');
```

Drupal removes the parenthesis and encapsulates the function in quotes.

How would I go about adding a condition as such.

Answer (score 10):

Ok figured out my own answer! Very silly but after spending over an hour searching, I bet I could help someone down the road.

I changed

```
$this->query->condition('MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(n.date))', 12, '=');
```

To

```
$this->query->where('MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(n.date)) = :val', array('val'=>12));
```

Works like a charm!!!

Comment: You've got a small typo in there, `array('val'=>12)` needs to be `array(':val'=>12)`

Comment: Doesn't matter...PDO can take it either way